# API/CLI to trigger KVM actions

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm

I could successfully create a VM with CLI/API in VMWare but I'm struggling with KVM.

Is there a (similar to VMware) way to trigger KVM actions like:

- provision a new vm
- start a vm
- stop a vm

I've not found any api/webservice documentation that covers that.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found that https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-install can do most of the things I'm looking for.

This can be closed, as I don't expect any answers that will cover the last 10% (select storage, vlan, ...)